# xslt: substring-before

Tags: xslt, substring

I have the folowing xml code:

```
<weather-code>14 3</weather-code>
<weather-code>12</weather-code>
<weather-code>7 3 78</weather-code>
```

Now i'd like to only grab the first number of each node to set a background image. So for each node i have the folowing xslt:

```
<xsl:attribute name="style">
  background-image:url('../icon_<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(weather-code, ' ')" />.png');
</xsl:attribute>
```

Problem is that substring before doesn't return anything when there's no space. Any easy way around this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`xsl:when`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_when.asp) and `contains`:

```
<xsl:attribute name="style">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(weather-code, ' ')">
      background-image:url('../icon_<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(weather-code, ' ')" />.png');
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>background-image:url('../icon_<xsl:value-of select="weather-code" />.png');</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: Xslt conditionals are ICK! I like Ledhund's solution, but this is technically correct.

Answer (score 24):

You can make sure that there is always a space, maybe not the prettiest but at least it's compact :)

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before( concat( weather-code, ' ' ) , ' ' )" />
```

Comment: +1 avoids conditionals which lead to other problems in a use case I have

Comment: This is also very helpful if you're stuck using an earlier version xml parser that doesn't support substring-before-if-contains.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`functx:substring-before-if-contains`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_substring-before-if-contains.html)

> The `functx:substring-before-if-contains` function performs `substring-before`, *returning the entire string if it does not contain the delimiter*. It differs from the built-in `fn:substring-before` function, which returns a zero-length string if the delimiter is not found.

Looking at [the source code](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx-1.0-doc-2007-01.xsl), it's implemented as follows:

```
<xsl:function name="functx:substring-before-if-contains" as="xs:string?">
<xsl:param name="arg" as="xs:string?"/>
<xsl:param name="delim" as="xs:string"/>
<xsl:sequence select=
  "if (contains($arg,$delim)) then substring-before($arg,$delim) else $arg"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: that xsl:sequence thing looks useful. I have already implemented Oded's method, but i surely will give this a try next time a face something similar.