# XPath: Limit cell content, if delimiter exists

Tags: xpath

I need to get the content of a cell, which occasionally contains a `','` character. If so, I need to isolate the content to the portion before the `','` character.

```
substring-before(//td[contains(text(),'Dokumentnummer')]/following-sibling::td[1],\",\")
```

This gives me the desired substring, but only *if* a `','` exists. How can I make it return the whole string, if it *does'nt* exist?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100132/xslt-substring-before

Comment: Thanks. I need to do it in a single XPath Statement, as I'm not working in an XML-context. I'm using the Translator Framework of Zotero `FW.Xpath("")`

Comment: Which version of XPath is supported? XPath 2.0 added an `if`-expression, http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-conditionals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `','` before calling substring-before, thus making sure there will allways be at least one comma:

```
substring-before(concat(//td[contains(text(),'Dokumentnummer')]/following-sibling::td[1],
                             ','),
                 ',')
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you - one of those hit-the-forehead-moments. One detail: The function is named `concat()`