# XSLT substring - take all values before specific string

Tags: xml, xslt, substring

I have elements:

```
<A>11511/direction=sink</A>
<B>110/direction=src</B>
```

Of course there are some elements without `/direction` suffix that is importnat to mention.

If elements A and B contain string `/direction`... I want to have the value before string `/direction`.
If elements do not contain `/direction` then take regular value as usual.
What should I add in `value-of` clause ?

```
<newElementA><xsl:value-of select="A"/></newElementA>
<newElementB><xsl:value-of select="B"/></newElementB>
```

I tried with `<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(A,'/')"/>` but then values which do not have value `/direction` are set with value null which is not correct

I also tried this but then getting error:

```
     <newelementA><xsl:value-of select="if (contains(A,'/')) 
then substring-before(A,'/') else A"/></newelementA>
```

I want to have values `11511`and`110` in result.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xslt: substring-before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100132/xslt-substring-before)

Comment: It is not a duplicate of this question because if I put <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(A,'/')"/>  I am getting null values for those elements which do not contain /direction in the value.., Can you please help me?

Comment: Are you limited to XSLT 1.0?  If you can use XSLT 2.0 or above, you have access to regex functions that are more flexible than the older `substring` functions.  Please clarify which version of XSLT you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use conditional processing,
and [choose](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl:choose)
between alternative actions depending on the content.

For example, this input (only using A for simplicity):

```
<root>
  <A>11511/direction=sink</A>
  <A>test</A>
</root>
```

with this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <newRoot>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </newRoot>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Create newElementA -->
  <xsl:template match="A">
    <newElementA>
      <xsl:call-template name="chooseContent"/>
    </newElementA>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Reusable template to determine element content -->
  <xsl:template name="chooseContent">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(.,'/direction')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'/direction')"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Ignore unknown elements -->
  <xsl:template match="*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

results in:

```
<newRoot>
  <newElementA>11511</newElementA>
  <newElementA>test</newElementA>
</newRoot>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use XSLT 2.0 or newer, the regular-expression function `replace` gives you the flexibility you need.

Example:

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '(.*?)/.*$', '$1')"/>
```

I've confirmed that this produces the output you say you want for any string `1235sdfa/sdff93rjdf`, and also for any string `asda98273jasdf` that does not contain a `/`.

Comment: Ah yes, it could be so simple. Hopefully, XSLT 2.0 will be more widely supported in the near future.

Comment: @Meyer -- If you're using the Microsoft XML libraries, don't expect XSLT 2.0 any time soon.

Comment: Oh well. I'm mostly bound to Linux with libxml2, where XSLT 2.0 seems equally unlikely. Hence my answer for good old portable 1.0.